# Wordpress Shortcodes in Footer wont Work

Tags: wordpress, templates, footer

I want to display a Plugin for my Contact form. The Problem is that I want to place it in the Footer. So I took the shortcode

```
[Contact_Form_Builder id="1"]
```

And pasted it via

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[Contact_Form_Builder id="1"]' ); ?>
```

in the Footer, but it display still just a Text. Do you have a idea how i can fix this?
Here is the example: 
http://codefragment.eu/high/

Comment: That doesn't make any sense...You pasted this in the **footer.php** file? Or in a widget?

Comment: In the footer.php and yea it also makes no sense to me either! I also tried it to put it in a template. The same result

Comment: Does it even work in the post editor? It sounds like a plugin issue...

Comment: Yep it works in the Editor, but I can try to put different shortcodes into the footer.php to test it.

Comment: oh you were right! It is a Plug In Problem, see here: http://codefragment.eu/high/
But in Pages/Editor it is working... omg... -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add the following code to your `functions.php` file

   > ```
   > add_filter('widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
   > add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
   > ```
   >
   > The second line is the one that makes the shortcodes work, but you’ll
   >   want to include both. If you check “add paragraphs automatically” on
   >   the widget, WordPress will apply the autop filter — the one that turns
   >   your line breaks into paragraph and break tags. If a shortcode is on
   >   its own line, it would normally get wrapped in a paragraph tag. The
   >   first line prevents that from happening.
   >
   > [Source](http://stephanieleary.com/2010/02/using-shortcodes-everywhere/)
2. Then place your shortcode (just as your first code block) in your footer using a text widget

A [similar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-widget/) is also available.